# AngularJS, set class on button when input has change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field that is a filter for a long list. Next to the input field is a search icon. Basically when the user starts typing, I need to change the icon class.

I have my text field setup like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="change()" ng-model="query" />
<button class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
```

Inside my controller I have defined:

```
$scope.change = function()
{
    //change the class of button based on the length of the input field     
}
```

Not really sure how I go about determining if there is input in the field using angular and changing the class. Am I taking the right approach here? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ng-class on your ng-model

```
<i ng-class="{'icon-search': query.length}"></i>
```

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear. The class is initially a search icon and I need the class to turn into `icon-refresh`. I think I figured it out though, its `<i class="icon-search" ng-class="{'icon-refresh': query.length}"></i>` thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use ngClass. Your function $scope.change should return the class name, so

```
<button ng-class="change()"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
```

and your controller function would look something like:

```
$scope.change = function() {
    if(something){
        return "classA";
    }
    else{
        return "classB";
    }
};
```

Comment: When would the change() method be invoked? Only the first time the UI is rendered?